# Backbone.js Redirect to External Url

Tags: backbone.js

I am having trouble redirecting to an external url. I want to know how I can redirect to, for example, http://www.google.com from inside my router.

I know I can use the routers .navigate function but that redirects to a different view. How would I go about redirecting to an external url.

Each time I try I use:

```
window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
```

But it complains because it is expecting a MIME type of document and the current MIME type is application/json. So how can i change the MIME type inside javascript?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

EDIT:
Removed `window.location.reload()`, since this will just reload the same page.

Comment: Nope, that puts it into an infinite loop for reloading the same page.

Comment: "But it complains" - can you show what you see in console? Also, are you using `history.pushState()`?